# How to construct the hashed token signature for Azure Cosmos DB REST API to list users?

Tags: python, azure, api, azure-cosmosdb, unauthorized

According to the documentation for the Cosmos DB REST API, with every API call, the Authorization header must be set. The value for this is constructed as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources

I am implementing this in Python as follows:

```
def get_authorisation_token(verb, resource_type, resource_id, date, master_key):
     key = base64.b64decode(master_key)

     text = f"""{verb.lower()}\n{resource_type.lower()}\n{resource_id.lower()}\n{date.lower()}\n\n"""

     text_encoded = text.encode('utf-8')

     signature_hash = hmac.new(key, text_encoded, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
     signature = base64.b64encode(signature_hash).decode()

     key_type = 'master'
     version = '1.0'

     uri = f'type={key_type}&ver={version}&sig={signature}'
     uri_encoded = urllib.parse.quote(uri)

     return uri_encoded
```

Since this is sent with every call, the auth token needs to be re-created to match the request URL. So, for example to get a list of databases, one must provide the resource type to be `dbs` and the resource link/ID to be an empty string with the URL: `https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/`

The part I cannot figure out, is the correct combination of resource type and resource ID/link to get all users from a particular database. Documentation can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-users

I have tried some combinations but nothing returns the users, I just get a 401:

```
{
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'get\nusers\ndbs/<db_name>\nmon, 09 nov 2020 23:37:24 gmt\n\n'\r\nActivityId: 697a4159-f160-4aab-ae90-6cb5eaadb710, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.11.0"
}
```

Comment: the resource type should be `users` and the resource link should be `dbs/{<db name>}`

Comment: I tried the resource type being `users` and the link being `dbs/db_name` but that still did not work. The same error as above is returned

Comment: Ok. I see. I will do a test.

Comment: Yesterday i faced same issue, my issue is that i'm generating the hash signature incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
from wsgiref.handlers import format_date_time
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime
import base64
from urllib.parse import quote
import hmac
from hashlib import sha256
import requests
from azure.cosmos.auth import GetAuthorizationHeader
from azure.cosmos.cosmos_client import CosmosClientConnection

master_key = ''
database_name = ''
key = base64.b64decode(master_key)
verb = 'GET'
resource_type = 'users'
resource_id = f'dbs/{database_name}'
now = datetime.now()
stamp = mktime(now.timetuple())
date = format_date_time(stamp)
print(date)
text = "{verb}\n{resource_type}\n{resource_id}\n{date}\n{other}\n".format(
    verb=(verb.lower() or ''),
    resource_type=(resource_type.lower() or ""),
    resource_id=(resource_id or ""),
    date=date.lower(),
    other="".lower())

body = text.encode("utf-8")
digest = hmac.new(key, body, sha256).digest()
signature = base64.encodebytes(digest).decode("utf-8")
key_type = 'master'
version = '1.0'
uri = f'type={key_type}&ver={version}&sig={signature[:-1]}'
uri_encoded = quote(uri)

url = "https://<>.documents.azure.com:443/dbs/<>/users"

payload = {}
headers = {
    'Authorization': uri_encoded,
    'x-ms-date': date,
    'x-ms-version': '2018-12-31'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jim for the help, this solved it indeed. The resourceType and resourceId were incorrect in my code.